# How to draw inside a node in tikzpicture with an edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

How can I draw such graphs using `tikzpicture`?

Comment: it would be helpful to upload your code which can be compiled

Comment: I don't have code for it. But this is the figure I want to draw using tikzpicture

Comment: Just posting an image and asking 'how to draw this' are not reasonable questions to ask on this website. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) showing what you have tried so far and what specific technical issues you are facing. You can start by looking at the `automata` library provided with TikZ and documented in [the TikZ manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: Hello and welcome. What do these diagrams represent?

Comment: Points-to information of pointer variables

Comment: You can use the `Pics` see the `Pics: Small Pictures on Paths` section of the TikZ manual.

Comment: What are these `Points-to-information of pointer variables`? Can you give an internet address that explains what they are?

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2019/lectures/pointsTo.pdf

Comment: See some examples here https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/

Comment: @mehuljain The graphs you have given as links are much simpler than the ones you have shown in your question. Please make a freehand drawing of the basic box what you would like to get

Comment: You can group and shift elements using scope.  You can put entire tikzpictures into saveboxes and display them inside nodes.

Comment: Voters of closure, why close a question that already has an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Defining `pics` following chapter 18 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual is definitely the way to go. The code below defines two pics, `2box` and `3box` for the boxes that contain two or three circles or squares, respectively. The `2box` is slightly easier as it takes only four arguments: the labels in the two circles and the the labels above and below the arrows. Using this you can draw the top box using

```
\pic at (0,0) {2box={r,a,1{\mid}0,01}};
```

The `pic` defines the following useful nodes:

- `ra` for the entire box
- `ra-r` for the first circle
- `ra-a` for the second circle

This is partly for drawing the picture and partly for drawing the arrows later on. The `3box` pic is similar but it takes seven arguments: the three node labels and the four labels above and below the two arrows.

With these in place it is just a matter of drawing the boxes, using the `2box` and `3box`, and then drawing the edges. At first I thought to use the `positioning` library to place the nodes but, sadly, `pics` and `positioning` do not play well together, so I have placed everything by hand to produce:

[image]

To make it easier to change, I have applied a generous dose of styling. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = {-{LaTeX}, thick},
  label/.style = {pos=0.4, font=\scriptsize},
  mynode/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=3pt, thick, draw=black},
  onode/.style = {circle, mynode},
  snode/.style = {rectangle, mynode},
  box/.style = {thick, fill=gray!50, draw=black, anchor=south west},
  pics/2box/.style args = {#1,#2,#3,#4}{% a,b,top,bot
    code = {
        \node[box, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm](#1#2) at (0,0){};
        \node[onode] (#1#2-#1) at (0.4,0.5){#1};
        \node[onode] (#1#2-#2) at (1.6,0.5){#2};
        \draw[arrow](#1#2-#1) -- node[label,above]{$#3$}
                                 node[label,below]{$#4$} (#1#2-#2);
    }
  },
  pics/3box/.style args = {#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7}{% a,b,c,top,bot,top,bot}
    code = {
        \node[box, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm](#1#2#3) at (0,0){};
        \node[snode] (#1#2#2-#1) at (0.4,1.5){#1};
        \node[snode] (#1#2#2-#2) at (0.4,0.5){#2};
        \node[onode] (#1#2#2-#3) at (1.6,1){#3};
        \draw[arrow](#1#2#2-#1.east) to[out=20, in=135]
            node[label,above]{$#4$} node[label,below]{$#5$} (#1#2#2-#3);
        \draw[arrow](#1#2#2-#2.east) to[out=-20, in=225]
            node[label,above]{$#6$} node[label,below]{$#7$} (#1#2#2-#3);
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,9) {2box={r,a,1{\mid}0,01}};
    \pic at (0,6) {3box={b,q,m,1{\mid}0,02,2{\mid}0,02}};
    \pic at (1,4) {2box={q,b,1{\mid}0,03}};
    \pic at (0,2) {2box={e,p,1{\mid}2,04}};
    \pic at (0,0) {2box={q,e,1{\mid}0,05}};
    \draw[arrow] (ra.south)--(bqm.north);
    \draw[arrow] (bqm.south)--(qb.north);
    \draw[arrow] (bqm) to[out=250, in=120](ep);
    \draw[arrow] (ep.south)--(qe.north);
    \draw[arrow] (qe.south)--++(0,-0.5);
    \draw[thick](0.5,10.6) -- ++(0,-0.1)--++(1,0)--++(0,0.1);
    \draw[{LaTeX}-,thick](ra.north)--++(0,0.5);
    \draw[arrow,rounded corners]
    (2.5,4)--++(0,-0.3)--++(1,0)--++(0,6.65)--++(-2,0)--++(0,-0.35);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the definition of the `2box` and `3box` are just little pieces of fairly similar [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) code. Inside the definition of the `pics`relative coordinates are used. I have left the `\delta` labels as an exercise.

Comment: +1 Well done, bravo!